# Error setting annotation value as Class<?> from a constant, why?

Tags: java, annotations

This is my annotation:

```
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD } )
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AuditUpdate
{
    Class<?> value();
}
```

By this way it is ok:

```
@AuditUpdate(User.class)
void someMethod(){}
```

But by this way:

```
private static final Class<?> ENTITY_CLASS = User.class;
@AuditUpdate(ENTITY_CLASS)
void someMethod(){}
```

I have this compilation error:

```
The value for annotation attribute AuditUpdate.value must be a class literal
```

Why? What does that mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that you must pass a class literal, rather than a variable (even if constant).

A class literal is well defined in the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#251530):

> **15.8.2 Class Literals**
>
> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class,
>   interface, array, or primitive type followed by a `.' and the token
>   class. The type of a class literal is Class. It evaluates to the Class
>   object for the named type (or for void) as defined by the defining
>   class loader of the class of the current instance.

So, you can't do that.

Comment: @francadaval - The information for the annotation is being resolved at compile time, and what you're doing would require the static initialization to have run to be able to determine the value of the class.To take this to an extreme - what if you had: ... ENTITY_CLASS = pick_my_class();  instead?  Now the compiler would have to somehow magically know what would be returned.  They decided to only allow literals, because the compiler can simply resolve it.

Comment: @James +1 for completing the answer.