# Generic Class Type on Annotations

Tags: java, generics

Is this possible?

```java
class MyService<T> {

    @MyAnnotation(T.class)
    private String myProperty;
}
```

Compiler doesn't like it. How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

I found I can't. See [Error setting annotation value as Class<?> from a constant, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564854/error-setting-annotation-value-as-class-from-a-constant-why).

Comment: Try this:private T myProperty;

Comment: Sorry, I actually asked about `T.class` part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not possible.

The parameters to the annotations must be compile-time constant values (such as String, numerical constants, or class literals, such as `User.class`), and a generic parameter `T` is not defined at compile time.

Furthermore, if `T` is a type parameter, then `T.class` is not valid Java code in any circumstances, due to something called *type erasure* (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure)). If you need to know what is the class of a type parameter `T` in runtime, there are some ways. For example:

```
class Repository<T> {
  private final Class<T> type;
  Repository(Class<T> type) { this.type = type; }
  T load(int id) { ... can use type here ... }
}
```

Also, be sure to check Google Guava (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained)) and/or Guice (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) and [here](https://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html)). These 2 libraries provide ways to inject -- or otherwise determine -- the class represented by `T` at runtime without having to pass it in the constructor.

The techniques used by these libraries are based on the fact that, although you cannot access the information on type parameters for a given `Class<?>`, you can access the information on super types of that class. So, if you have, say `abstract class Service<T>` and you have a `class MyService extends Service<String>`, you can use a `Class<MyService>` to call `getGenericSuperclass()` on it and use the result to obtain the value of `T`, which is `String`. This is tedious, error-prone, so be sure to use a library to do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

That is **not possible** due to type erasure. You can do something like this.

```
class MyConcreteService extends MyService<String> {

    @MyAnnotation(String.class)
    private String myProperty;
}
```

You can create concrete instance of service where the generic parameter is known and then you can use the annotation as the class is known to you. Yes that is tedious a bit.